# Access is denied when querying LDAP from .Net Core WEB API deployed to IIS Server

Tags: c#, authentication, iis, ldap, asp.net-core-webapi

I have developed a WEB API application in .Net Core 2.0 which is to perform LDAP CRUD operations. Locally, this works; I can perform all my GETs, PUTs, POSTs successfully to LDAP.  I have also installed IIS locally, published my application, and set up the application in IIS with Authentication set to Windows Authentication.  When I hit the site using localhost in my url (for example, "http://locahost/myapp/Users"), I can successfully perform all the CRUD actions I set up.  BUT, when I set the url to the server name (for example, "http://servername.mydomain.com/myapp/Users"), I enter in a valid username and password for my domain user, and I get an "Access is denied".  And just FYI, I am able to hit "http://servername.mydomain.com/myapp/", just not "http://servername/myapp/Users" or any other page that queries LDAP.

I have traced this down to when I create the PrincipalContext:

```
context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com");
```

Diving into the values of context, context.ConnectedServer ends up having an issue:

> {System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext}
>
> ConnectedServer: '(ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ldap.Url)).ConnectedServer' threw an exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException'
>
> Container: null
>
> ContextType: Domain
>
> Name: "mydomain.com"
>
> Options: Negotiate | Signing | Sealing
>
> UserName: null

I am not understanding why I cannot successfully at least read LDAP values from web api by hitting my server this way.  I am guessing that it has something to do with the authentication.  If someone could offer any insight, I would greatly appreciate it!

**UPDATE 11/09/2017:**

I was able to get a little further with my progress. I can now access my site on my machine referencing the site with the fully qualified name by following what is on this site:

Browser Configuration (Chrome is to be configured in IE settings)

https://ping.force.com/Support/PingFederate/Integrations/How-to-configure-supported-browsers-for-Kerberos-NTLM

** Make sure that you clear your entire cache as well 
Chrome>>Settings>>Advanced Settings>>Clear Browser Data>>Select All Boxes>>OK

**NOW....** Now that I have it deployed in IIS locally, I now what to set this up on an IIS server and hit the website from my local machine (in the same domain).  For instance, if I set up my website on an IIS server, named "iis-server.mydomain.com", I tried to hit the site: "http://iis-server.mydomain.com/my-app" from my local machine, and I get prompted for my login and password.

If I follow that document in that link to set all the browser settings, I would think that it would work just as it did locally.  But low and behold it doesn't...

Comment: I suspect the existing Services are running as Admin while you new service is running with normal credentials.

Comment: @jdweng Please excuse my ignorance.  I'm new to setting up Net core applications on IIS,  How do I go about validating your suspicion?

Comment: See installing : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer

Comment: Update:  I was able to get a little further with my progress.  I can now access my site on my machine referencing the site with the fully qualified name by following what is on this site:

https://ping.force.com/Support/PingFederate/Integrations/How-to-configure-supported-browsers-for-Kerberos-NTLM

** Make sure that you clear your entire cache as well 
Chrome>>Settings>>Advanced Settings>>Clear Browser Data>>Select All Boxes>>OK

Comment: You probably ended up with a bad cookie and clearing cache deleted the cookie.  Often when developing an application there are initially errors that generate bad cookies.  So you have to delete cookies as you make changes to get rid of the bad cookies.

Comment: @jdweng - Maybe, but I updated my issue with my progress and I am getting the same error as before, when querying LDAP.  This time, I am trying to hit the site: "http://iis-server.mydomain.com/my-app" from my local machine, and I get prompted for my login and password. I don't think I should be prompted with a user name and password but if I go ahead and put in my username and password, I get the same error stated in my initial post.

Comment: The sounds like a Group Policy issue.  You need to talk to your MIS department.  I think there is an issue running an application from one computer to another computer.  Deleting cookie required you to re-enter the credentials to allow you to remotely connect to the server.  But this isn't going to solve the more general issue.  Connecting to a webpage the credentials are automatically set to a GUEST Account. The GUEST Account has limited privileges.Running as Admin give more access but doesn't set the environment variables.So I suspect you may have issue with pathnames not being set properly.

Comment: Check the Event Logs on Server to see if there are any error messages at same time you are trying to connect.